# how to add some image on openlayers under controls zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm so very newbie with openlayers, i just want to add some image under control zoom in/out on openlayers, like compass image or anything, where the image location is inside IMG folder. What exactly the code i can use it on openlayers?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the second map in this example: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/zoom.html (use custom markup for ZoomControl).

Comment: if you do not mind, can you show me an example of code? because i just can do it if there is an some example. But don't do it if that's make you troubling :) Thank you ^_^

Comment: There a link to the source code in the examples. I don’t see what you can miss…

Comment: @tonio, Your link is dead

Comment: @jlandercy link fixed.